# Networkx : real vs integer internals and hierarcial graph plot?

Tags: python, plot, networkx, hierarchical

I'm using the following plot() function which I stumbled upon after experiments. 
[previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286858/networkx-draw-graph-in-layers/42322196#42322196)

```
def plot(self):
    plt.figure()
    pos = nx.graphviz_layout(self.g, prog='dot')
    nx.draw(self.g, pos, node_size=660, node_color='#aaaaff' )
```

The graph looks **OK** (it is hierarchal, with 3 layers) if the internally some edge connections use floating point numbers like the following example Look at 2.0, 3.0,... :

```
{1: {21: {}},
 2: {22: {}},
 3: {},
 21: {2.0: {}, 52: {}},
 22: {3.0: {}},
 52: {22.0: {}}}
```

[image]

But if the internals are pure integers like the example below everything goes **WRONG** :

```
{1: {21: {}},
 2: {22: {}},
 3: {},
21: {2: {}, 52: {}},
22: {3: {}},
52: {22: {}}}
```

[image]

It is the same for bigger graphs too. This was just one example.

Any idea why this may happen ?? and solution ...

Comment: Please explain the problem.  Those two outputs are topologically identical.

Comment: One is plotted hierarchical the other is not.

Answer (score 1):

If NetworkX.draw internally produces a dictionary of edges, it's quite possible that the first example produces edges in a different order: floats and ints do not hash identically.  I'm hardly an expert on this package, but I don't see anything in the NextworkX documentation that guarantees, or even hints, that it will print the graph in some form respecting the first-listed node as a visual root.

In short, you get the graph in whatever form the **draw** routine's internals find convenient.

I assume you can make the desired changes yourself; if not, please provide a fully-functional [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  That promotes more detailed responses.

---

I did a little more [reading](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw).
You *can* specify positions; if you default them (as you did in the posted example), then the **layout** method takes over, and you get whatever it finds convenient.